# In MS Word, how can I get a Table Of Contents without the text in headings?

Tags: ms-word, heading, tableofcontents

After applying heading, the result I want is like this: the upper line with the word "Chapter" and a automatic number of chapter, and the lower line with the name of chapter

[image]

And corresponding table of contents need just take the number of chapter and the name of chapter, not the word "Chapter", like this

[image]

I have tried to remove the word "Chapter" from the numbering setting, the corresponding table of contents is OK, but the result item itself will have only number+nameOfChapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `TC` fields which contain the chapter numbers. However they won't be automatically numbered. There might be a way to get them to autonumber by meddling with the styles etc but I haven't tried that part. In terms of your TOC look and feel, try this with TC fields....

To add a TC field, go to the `Insert` ribbon, then `Quick Parts`, choose `Field...` and scroll in the left list till you see TC. Type `Chapter 1` into the 'Text entry`box and`1` into Outline level. Press OK to insert it at the current cursor point

Now amend your TOC by pressing `ALT+F9` to show field codes.

Update it like this, making sure you replace 'style' with the name of heading style used for your `Graphical modeling...` bit.

`{TOC \o "1-1" \f \t "style,2" \n 1-1}`

If your style is called `Alex Style` then change it to:

`{TOC \o "1-1" \f \t "Alex Style,2" \n 1-1}`

To explain what's happening in the TOC, see below:

```
`\o "1-1"` - this omits page numbers from level 1 (chapter 1 - we don't want a page number on that bit, if i've understood correctly. Change it to `\o "1-2"` to remove the page number for the `Graphical modeling` line too.)

`\f` - allows the `TC` field to be included in the TOC

`\t "style,2"` - adds a style other than the built-in heading styles to the TOC. We want this custom style to be on level 2 so it appears under the TC field. 

`\n 1-1` - probably redundant as it does what `\o "1-1" does.
```

Once you've amended this field code, right click the TOC and `Update field` then `Update entire table`.

Some images below which might help to illustrate it better. Note that I am using a style called `Block Paragraph 1` and my TOC may well look different to yours but the principal is the same.

[image: TOC with field codes showing]
[image: TOC with field codes off]

A good resource for anything to do with TOCs is this page: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm